# Can one validate marshalled XML with JAXB 2.0?

Tags: java, validation, jaxb

Apparently in version 2 of JAXB - the validator class has been deprecated - does this mean the marshaller is automatically validating your XML?  If so it doesn't seem to be complaining about some of the incorrect XML I am forming!  Can anyone give me some advice on how I can validate marshalled XML to make sure it conforms to the XSD schema.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Validation capabilities have been expanded in JAXB 2.0 through the use of the JAXP 1.3 Schema Validation Framework.

Where before you did:

```
unmarshaller.setValidating(true);
```

now you need to do:

```
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(
    javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("myschema.xsd"));
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
```

If you pass null into `setSchema`, it disables validation.

Please check [this reference](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html).

Comment: Do you put the same code for a MARSHALLER - this code looks like it's for an UNMARSHALLER...

Comment: Yes. You can do the exact same thing for marshaller and unmarshaller.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to verify the Java objects generate valid XML according to a schema, look at the JAXB-Verification project:

https://jaxb-verification.dev.java.net/

It is a JAXB RI plugin to xjc that will generate an ObjectVerifier implementation for the XML schema.  This avoids having to marshal the Java objects in order to validate the XML.

Comment: JAXB Verification is obsolete, I no longer develop it. Was only for JAXB 1.x by the way, not for JAXB 2.