# Why doesn't JAXB want to validate

Tags: java, xml, schema, xsd, jaxb

1. I wrote some Java classes and annotated them with the JAXB annotations.
2. After that I used schemagen to generate an xsd.
3. Then I build an object graph and marshalled it to a xml file.
4. I modified the xml file so that it was not valid anymore.

I wanted to use the xsd in the hope the JAXB unmarshalling fails. But it doesn't. Why?

JAXB is reading a schema (if the schema XML is wrong JAXB gives an exception) but it seams that JAXB is ignoring the schema while reading.

```
 SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
 Schema schema = sf.newSchema(getClass().getResource( "/schema1.xsd"));
 JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
 Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
 unmarshaller.setSchema( schema );

 Customer c = JAXB.unmarshal(file, Customer.class);
```

The written XML starts like that:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <ns2:customer xmlns:ns2="http://bla.com/">
```

Even the attached ValidationEventCollector didn't give any information:

```
 unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new JAXBEventCollector());
```

JAXBEventCollector is:

```
 class JAXBEventCollector extends ValidationEventCollector
 {
   @Override
   public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event)
   {
       System.out.println(event.getLocator());
       return true;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Duplicate: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805989/can-one-validate-marshalled-xml-with-jaxb-2-0

Comment: Of course not. Please take the time and read both questions carefully.

Comment: as per lexicore exact dupe - voted to close

Comment: Sorry, but I think both of you either don't program Java or don't understand this question. It is totally different from then the quoted one.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate of the one quoted.  Can you provide more details as to which implementation of JAXB you are using (Metro, MOXy, etc) and version.  Is the last line just a typo, you create an unmarshaller called unmarshaller but then do JAXB.unmarshal?

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work.  A couple of things to look out for:

- Is the URL for your schema coming back as null?
- Is your last line a typo "JAXB.unmarshal(file, Customer.class)", or is JAXB another unmarshaller without a schema set on it.

Below is a fragment of code that definitely throws errors when invalid XML is unmrshalled.  This code works correctly with both the [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) and Metro (RI) JAXB implementations.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    File xsd = new File("customer.xsd");
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(xsd); 
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller(); 
    unmarshaller.setSchema( schema ); 

    FileInputStream xml = new FileInputStream("invalid.xml");
    unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
}
```

With Metro the error looks like:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'phone-numbers'. One of '{phoneNumbers}' is expected.]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:514)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:215)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
    at example.gettingstarted.Demo2.main(Demo2.java:23)
```

With MOXy the error looks like:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.3.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'phone-numbers'. One of '{phoneNumbers}' is expected.]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:114)
    at example.gettingstarted.Demo2.main(Demo2.java:23)
```

Comment: If the URL to the Schema would be wrong there would be a NullPointerException. So this is not the error. But you directed me to the error and I could bang my head against the wall. Thanks! You make my day :) Of course JAXB.unmarshal() doesn't have the context, right is

Customer c = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal( file );